# Connect a Range Slider with a DataTable (Flask)

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, rangeslider

I'm looking to create a date range slider with my datatable for my flask app. I'm not quite sure how to connect the range slider effectively with the date values.

I'm currently trying [ion range slider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/) but am not tied to that as a solution. Would appreciate some working solutions to help guide me on this.

The dataset here is just a dummydataset, but the data which I'm pulling from comes in a proper date format. This is what I got up to so far. I'm quite new with Javascript and JQuery.

---

**Python**

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, render_template_string, request, flash
import json
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "test"

test_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Australia', 'Report #1', 'Category #1', '2021-01-01', 'https://www.google.com', 'https://reliefweb.int/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/previews/c5/2d/c52de4ba-42d8-4383-8310-eb1a6966e803.png'],
    ['Canada', 'Report #2', 'Category #1', '2021-01-01', 'https://www.google.com', 'https://reliefweb.int/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/previews/c5/2d/c52de4ba-42d8-4383-8310-eb1a6966e803.png'],
    ['China', 'Report #3', 'Category #2', '2021-01-01', 'https://www.google.com', 'https://reliefweb.int/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/previews/c5/2d/c52de4ba-42d8-4383-8310-eb1a6966e803.png']],
    columns=['Country', 'Title', 'Category', 'Date', 'Link', 'Image'])
test_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['Date'])
test_df = test_df.fillna("")
test_df = test_df.values.tolist()


@app.route("/hello")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", test_df=test_df)
```

**HTML/Javascript**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="filters">
        <input type="text" class="js-range-slider" name="my_range" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="main" id="tester">
        <table class="table mydatatable" id="table">
            <thead>
                <th> </th>
                <th> </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        function buildTable(data) {
            const table = document.getElementById('myTable')
            table.innerHTML = data.map(function (row) {
                let [Country, Title, Category, Date, Link, Image] = row;
                return `<tr>
        <td><br><br>
        <a href="${Link}" target='_blank'>
            <img class="tableThumbnail" src=${Image}><br><br></td></a>
        <td>
            <span class="tableTitle"><br><br><a href="${Link}" target='_blank'>${Title}</a><br></span>
            <span class="tableCountry"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;${Country}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="tableCategory">&nbsp;&nbsp;${Category}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="tableDate"><span><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="far fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;${Date}</span></span></td>
    </tr>`;
            }).join('');
        }


        const test_df = JSON.parse('{{ test_df|tojson }}');

        buildTable(test_df)

        //This is where I'm most stuck
        $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
            type: "double",
            min: 2020 - 01 - 01,
            max: 2021 - 01 - 01,
            from: 2020 - 01 - 01,
            to: 2021 - 01 - 01,
            grid: true
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.mydatatable').DataTable({
                "pagingType": "simple",
                "ordering": "false",
                "dom": '<<t>fip>'
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
```